# Debugging native c++ code in Flutter Desktop app / plugin

Tags: c++, flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, desktop

I'm creating native plugin implementation for Flutter desktop app (both Linux and Windows), and I'd like to debug plugin's C++ implementation. I only found guide how to do it with ios/android plaform code (https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/oem-debuggers).

So for I have tried the following:

1. Open "windows" directory with VSCode (install C/C++ / CMake / CMakeTools  plugins)
2. Select Cmake configuration
3. Select Debug (Bug) icon to start debugging (screenshot)

Unfortuntely I'm getting an error:

`The program '[18192] hello_windows.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).`

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71406447/7706354 .try this it will solve the problem