# Flutter-desktop windows plugin debug native c++ code

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I would like to create a Flutter desktop windows plugin.I want to debug the native c++ code . Is there any documentation or any article.[Debugging native c++ code in Flutter Desktop app / plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628081/debugging-native-c-code-in-flutter-desktop-app-plugin).Already asked here but any solution mentioned or answer.i could debug dart code only using android studio .Any solution accepted.

What i did?

This command i used to create windows plugin

```
flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin --platforms=windows hellp
```

Here i use android studio ide to manage my dart code .my flutter version 2.10.i already installed `visualstudio 2022` with `windows desktop developement kit` already mention in flutter document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the command used to create sample plugin

```
flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin --platforms=windows hellp
```

Same step used for **Visual-studio-code**

[image]

1. Windows(project root folder)  ==> Copy Path ==> your project path

[image]

2. Copy path
   [image]
3. File =>Open=>Folder

[image]
4. Select your flutter project windows folder

[image]
5. Debug your application in android studio
[image]

6. (Visual studio) Debug=>Attach process

[image]
7. (Visual studio) Debug=>Attach process

[image]
8. Debug your application again in android studio
[image]
9. now you can see it will hit on the visualstudio breakpoint

First Gif

[image]

Second Gif

[image]